# Yandex maps api - deliveryCalculator

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

Изучаю код примера расчета доставки для внедрения на сайт: [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator). Никак не могу понять, как мне отловить 2 события: до появления балуна и после закрытия балуна. Можете посоветовать?

Много нашел вариантов реализации, но почему-то не работает либо нужна доработка либо не в то место в коде вставляю код.

Изначально необходимо отображать панель маршрутизации, когда балуна нет, скрывать когда балун появился, и снова отобразить после закрытия балуна.

Смог сделать только такое(ниже строки вызова балуна): скрывать панель в момент появления балуна:

```
if (!activeRoute.balloon.isOpen()==true)
{
routePanelControl.options.set('visible',false);
}
```

Перехват события перед закрытием:

```
myMap.balloon.events.add('userclose', function (e) {
.....
.....
....
});
```

Не могу добиться чтобы этот код отработал...

Вот еще такой код нашел:

```
myMap.geoObjects.events
        .add('balloonopen', function (e) {
             alert('балун закрыт');
        })

        .add('balloonclose', function (e) {
           alert('балун закрыт');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что балун открывается не сам по себе. События **balloonopen / balloonclose** срабатывают для той сущности, для которой он вызывается ([одиночный геообъект](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject.html#GeoObject__events-summary), [ObjectManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.Balloon.html#objectManager.Balloon__events-summary), [Мультимаршрут](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.driving.Route.html#multiRouter.driving.Route__events-summary), etc.). То есть откуда вы открываете балун, туда вы и должны подписаться.